# Array of array in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

In a Postgres DB I have a field `field` defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    field character varying(255)[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::character varying[],
);
```

There I store values like:

```
ID   FIELD   
1    {{lower,0},{greater,10}}
2    {{something_else,7},{lower,5}}
```

1 - How can I select the lower/greater value? I'd like a query response like this:

```
ID   LOWER   
1    0
2    5
```

2 - How can I filter by those lower/greater values?

Thanks!

Comment: If the format is always EXACTLY like that you could do `SELECT id, field[1][2]`. However you're using `lower,5` like a key/value pair, but storing it as two completely unrelated (for all intents and purposes) or equal values. You should reconsider that design.

Comment: To store key/value pairs JSONB or hstore are much better choices or consider properly normalizing your data model

Comment: I've edited the question. I don't have always the same format, and I cannot change the design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty awkward to do but this accomplishes it. I use PG 9.3 so I don't know if there are better ways to do this in later versions.

```
SELECT id, (SELECT field[ss][2] FROM generate_subscripts(field, 1) ss WHERE field[ss][1] = 'lower') AS lower
FROM t;
```

Basically, for each record, generate the subscripts to use as indexes into the main array to access the subarrays. For each, look for an array where the first item is 'lower'. If found, return the value of the second item.